# Scala - overloading operators for custom wrappers

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

I wanted for a practice to create some kind of a monoid, ie. a custom wrapping class for common types that will allow me to tun basic operations on them:

```
abstract class WrappedVal[T](value: T) {
  def +(that: WrappedVal[T]): WrappedVal[T]
  def get: T = value
}

case class NumericValue(value: Double) extends WrappedVal[Double](value) {
  override def +(that: WrappedVal[Double]): NumericValue = NumericValue(value + that.get)
}

case class StringValue(value: String) extends WrappedVal[String](value) {
  override def +(that: WrappedVal[String]): StringValue = StringValue(value.substring(1) + that.get.substring(1))
}
```

In this way, I can for example do `NumericValue(3)+NumericValue(4)` and I get `NumericValue(7)`.

Then I wanted to wrap this value a bit more, so I added:

```
case class Entry(bucket: Integer, value: WrappedVal[_])
```

Now I have a function, that depending on params returns Entry types (which  always have the same value type, ie. either NumericValue or StringValue or SomeOtherValue) with the signature:

```
def readValue(vartype: String, value: String): WrappedVal[_] = {
    if(vartype == "String") StringValue(value)
    else NumericValue(value.toInt)
}
```

so effectively I get:

```
val l = List(Entry(1,NumericValue(1)), Entry(1,NumericValue(2)), Entry(1,NumericValue(3)))
```

The problem arises when I want to use my custom operator e.g. in reduce clause:

```
l.map(x => x.value).reduce(_+_)
```

This happens because scala can figure out the type during runtime (`l.map(x => x.value)` is of `List[WrappedVal[_]]` type.

Any hints on how can I fix this issue 'the proper way'?

Comment: I can parametrize Entry as `Entry[T](bucket: Integer, value:  WrappedVal[T])`, but I can tell the return type of readValue only during runtime, which causes all the mess - readValue returning WrappedValue[_].

Answer (score 0):

I was playing a bit with your code and got this to work

```
abstract class WrappedVal[T](value: T)(implicit A: ClassTag[T]) {
  def +(that: WrappedVal[_]): WrappedVal[T] = {
    classTag[T] match {
      case t if t == classTag[String] => StringValueFunctions.add(this.asInstanceOf[WrappedVal[String]], that.asInstanceOf[WrappedVal[String]]).asInstanceOf[WrappedVal[T]]
      case t if t == classTag[Double] => NumericValueFunctions.add(this.asInstanceOf[WrappedVal[Double]], that.asInstanceOf[WrappedVal[Double]]).asInstanceOf[WrappedVal[T]]
    }
  }
  def get: T = value
}

case class NumericValue(value: Double) extends WrappedVal[Double](value)
case object NumericValueFunctions {
  def add(value:WrappedVal[Double], that: WrappedVal[Double]): WrappedVal[Double] = NumericValue(value.get + that.get)
}

case class StringValue(value: String) extends WrappedVal[String](value) 
case object StringValueFunctions{
  def add(value: WrappedVal[String], that: WrappedVal[String]): WrappedVal[String] = StringValue(value.get.substring(1) + that.get.substring(1))
}
```

If you want this `l.map(x => x.value).reduce(_+_)` to work
you need a `def +(that: WrappedVal[_])` method, which is a bit ugly.

Hopefully it helps you to find 'the proper way'

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have a function, that depending on params returns Entry types (which always have the same value type, ie. either NumericValue or StringValue or SomeOtherValue)

The issue is that the compiler doesn't know this. Can you group your `readValue` calls to tell it? I.e.

```
case class Entries[T](entries: List[Entry[T]]) {
  def sum = entries.map(_.value).reduce(_ + _)
}

def readValues(...): Entries[_]
```

or, if you don't want to introduce `Entries` type, you could work with existentials: `List[Entry[T]] forSome { type T }`.